# Can't remove list-style-image

Tags: css, html

I have a strange problem.

As you can see here <del>http://www.skywarder.eu/blog/</del><sup>1</sup> there are two flags for languages on the right sidebar.

I'm struggling to remove the list-style-image but until now I didn't succeed. Could you give me an hand?

Thanks

Here's my css about that

```
/* qTranslate Widget */
.qtrans_language_chooser {
list-style:none;
}

.qtrans_language_chooser li {
float:left;
margin-left:3px;

}
```

<sup>1</sup>The website has changed, the link is not related to the question anymore.

Comment: i dont see any list styles (no dots), on firefox

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have an arrow image specified as the list-style-image. What are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry. Want to remove that image. I want to remove everything. :D
@j08691

Comment: Sooo, setting list-style-image to 'none' on .qtrans_language_chooser li isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @j08691 Ya it's already written like that but i dunno why it doesn't work. I still see the arrow o.O

Comment: Your CSS declaration for that rule is probably being overridden by another style that appears later in your code, or one that has greater specificity. Have you tried adding !important to the rule?

Comment: Ya i had tried. Anyway with @jmoerdyk answer i solved. I should specify better the rule. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrow is coming from this rule on line 572 of your style.css

```
.widget li {
    list-style-image: url("img/side_arrow.gif");
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

To override that one for just the translate widget you will need to add the following rule:

```
.widget .qtrans_language_chooser li {
    list-style: none;
}
```